# cameraOverlayView from ImagePickerController not displayed right?

Tags: xcode

I am using a customized overlay view for the camera in the imagePickerController. When  I take the picture, I get a Preview with the "Retake" and "Use" buttons. Unfortunately, the customized cameraOverlayView is still there in a portrait mode and screws the whole picture. Is there a way to remove the overlayView. I added the overlayView as a subview and then called the function [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
I also use -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *) info; later.

I hope you can help me with that because I have been stuck on that for the last two days and did not find any info on the web about it.

Thanks,
Nikola

Answer (score 0):

When you add you view make sure you are using [self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView addSubview:self.view];.